# SQL autoincrement with no gaps -- workarounds / best practices

Tags: sql, auto-increment

My application needs a table with an autoincrement primary key column with no gaps. As others have noted AUTOINCREMENT implementations typically cause gaps (txn rollbacks, deletes, etc.) Autoincrement with no gaps is straightforward to implement at the application layer, but I wonder if there's a better (more SQL'ish) way to approach this.

The reason why I prefer to have no gaps is because I imagine range-queries of the form

```
SELECT * 
FROM chainTable 
WHERE chn_id >= 10005003 AND chn_id <= 10005009
```

are faster than queries of the form

```
SELECT * 
FROM chainTable 
WHERE chn_id >= 10005003 
ORDER BY chn_id 
LIMIT 7
```

In my application, the selected rows were created in the same transaction. So my need that there be no gaps could be relaxed to values generated within the same transaction. So my question boils down to this:

Are AUTOINCREMENT column values generated **within** a transaction guaranteed to be contiguous (i.e. no gaps)?

My guess would still be "no", but I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If "within a transaction" is something that's important to your system, it seems logical to register and store that with the rows, whether it's an application-generated GUID, a transaction ID as provided by your database or something else. Range queries would be quickly satisfied by a time or ID range in combination with that ID. Relying on sequential IDs to convey any sort of semantics is never a good idea, even if you can make them gapless; the only reason they should be there is to make rows unique in the absence of a (convenient, indexable) business key.

Comment: Why do you imagine that the first query will perform faster than the second? What do you know about primary keys that makes you think the first would be faster? Based on my knowledge of clustered indices, keys, and the SQL optimizer, I would not expect the performance between the two queries to be significantly different.

Comment: You need to explain more why your app "needs" IDs to be contiguous. Such a requirement is pretty widely considered an anti-pattern. If you have some aspect of your design that requires continuity (i.e. all related records are within one ID block) then you probably have a design flaw.

Comment: You're probably better just implementing your logic using a normal auto-imcrementing ID for your keys and not worry about the odd gap left by a delete or rollback. If you *imagine* there will be a performance benefit to somehow enforcing no gaps then the problem is the *imagine* part. Most databases read data in pages, not individual rows, so in almost all cases reading a range of rows between two values will have identical IO regardless of any gaps.

Comment: Good comments here. Thank you! You've all convinced me I shouldn't worry about my "imagined" performance difference.

Comment: About the contiguous IDs. I still need these to be contiguous elsewhere.. The reason why is my tables are supposed to be ledgers (append-only), and the row-number figures prominently in the data model. https://github.com/crums-io/skipledger

Comment: If continuity is a hard demand, then relying on an autoincrement/identity is probably not the best idea, as they're only there to provide uniqueness (and optimized for that case). Generating contiguous values is (relatively) expensive because you need synchronization, regardless of where this happens; in the case of a database you probably want to write sprocs that handle inserts that explicitly take an exclusive lock so inserts cannot happen concurrently (the most appropriate mechanism varies by RDBMS, though a general approach with a `SERIALIZABLE` transaction is possible).

Answer (score 2):

overhead of managing id in the app is going to be more expensive than letting your sql engine handle it.

for your queries , there would be no noticeable performance difference as far as you have a proper index on that column.
however the second query might be slightly faster because It has to check only one condition.

Answer (score 0):

2 conclusions from your comments/answer:

1. The use case mentioned here is not apt. (No reason to expect a performance oomph; maybe the opposite.) But,
2. If your data model requires ascending numbers with no gaps, better off implementing it yourself.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine range-queries of the form

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM chainTable 
> WHERE chn_id >= 10005003 AND chn_id <= 10005009
> ```

> are faster than queries of the form

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM chainTable 
> WHERE chn_id >= 10005003 
> ORDER BY chn_id 
> LIMIT 7
> ```

You should try to prove this first. I don't think the first form is faster if an index is used for `chn_id`.

If an index is used, then the rows will be read in index order, therefore `ORDER BY chn_id` is a no-op. MySQL is already reading the rows in index order by `chn_id`, so it'll just continue reading the first 7 after the start of your range, and then stop because of the LIMIT.

I don't think you need a solution to make your auto-inc consecutive (that is, with no gaps).

For the record, it is certainly NOT the case that auto-increment will be consecutive within a transaction. If it were, then one transaction would block other sessions from inserting data.

> my tables are supposed to be ledgers (append-only), and the row-number figures prominently in the data model.

The auto-increment is NOT a row number. Don't try to use it as a row number.

You will always have gaps, if you rollback or delete rows. Or if an INSERT fails because of an error for instance a constraint violation. Also depending on what brand of RDBMS you are using, the implementation of auto-inc may not guarantee against gaps even under normal usage.